# TCP: One PC can connect to other's listening port but not vice versa

Tags: networking, tcp, socket, netcat

I have a local network (doesn't really matter if it's VPN or real local network - I've tried both).

One computer running Linux Mint opens a socket with

```
mint$ nc -l 4242
```

And the second one running OpenSUSE can connect and send messages to the socket:

```
suse$ nc 10.8.0.10 4242
```

But if I try to open a socket on Suse and connect from Mint - the connection won't establish. I don't have `ufw` firewall installed on Suse at all.

I tried to send TCP packets from Mint to a Windows PC and it worked well, so I guess, that the problem is in Suse machine.

I have also tried picking higher port numbers (55555 for example) just in case but with no luck.

`iptables -L -v` on Suse:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 272 23240 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
  28  5183 ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate ESTABLISHED
   0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED
  15  4984 input_ext  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
   0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix "SFW2-IN-ILL-TARGET "
   0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   0     0 LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix "SFW2-FWD-ILL-ROUTING "

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 47 packets, 7142 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 272 23240 ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain forward_ext (0 references)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain input_ext (1 references)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   2  1956 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             PKTTYPE = broadcast
   0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp source-quench
   0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
  13  3028 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             PKTTYPE = multicast
   0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             PKTTYPE = broadcast
   0     0 LOG        tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix "SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT "
   0     0 LOG        icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix "SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT "
   0     0 LOG        udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 ctstate NEW LOG level warning tcp-options ip-options prefix "SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT "
   0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain reject_func (0 references)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with tcp-reset
   0     0 REJECT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
   0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
```

What can cause this issue?

Comment: Do `iptables -L` on Suse.

Comment: @tomas I've added it to my question.

Comment: It looks like it will be better to replace the output of `iptables -L` with one of `iptables -L -v`. It will bring more details. Sorry for this.

Comment: @tomas updated with `iptables -L -v`

Comment: run on suse `sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 4242 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: @Babyy That worked! Could you write an answer so I can accept it. Could you as well explain why it is not working without this command, how to make these settings permanent if they aren't) and how do I make all ports to be able to accept connections, not just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this command:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 4242 -j ACCEPT
```

the last line of your suse `INPUT` chain is:

```
   0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

that means `DROP` all `INPUT` packet, with this command

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 4242 -j ACCEPT
```

we `I`nsert new rule for accept input packet top and before run `DROP` rule

and this rule not work for new connection :

```
ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate ESTABLISHED
```

because that stats is `ESTABLISHED` to this mean:

> RELATED - The connection is new, but is related to another connection
>   already permitted. ESTABLISHED - The connection is already
>   established.